# OpenLayers: Get distance from gpx

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have a gpx file. I'm displaying it on top of OSM using OpenLayers and [this example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openlayers_Track_example).

My requirement is to get distance of the route. How can i achieve that?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: That link would appear to be incorrect.

Comment: Please clarify "get distance of the route". Means length of the track? Means distance from where am i to the nearest segment of the track ?

Comment: Please stop crossposting https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/33195/openstreetmap-get-distance-from-gpx

Comment: @JohnBarça Sorry I edited the link

Comment: @GuillaumePelletier Yes, Length of the track (track given in the gpx file). ie, Real length(total kilometers in the track).

Comment: me too have same requirement.. please help..Urgent..

Comment: @MaM Sorry, I needed the answer right away.

Comment: I might undestand that you are stressed, but please also respect that a not much people are here to support you on GIS topic. So it's pretty time-consuming to read+answer the same questions. This time could be used to answer different quesions instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, A GPX is an XML file defining a set of Track Segment which holds a list of Track Points which are logically connected in order.

```
<trkseg>
     <trkpt lat='float' lon='float'/>
     <trkpt lat='float' lon='float'/>
     <trkpt lat='float' lon='float'/>
...
</trkseg>
```

All you need is to compute All the track segment length using distance from point to point (the points hold the lat and lon)
The distance from point to point will be compute using the following formula :

```
var radius = 6378137.0 ; // earth radius in meter
var DE2RA = 0.01745329252; // degre to radian conversion

// return the distance between (lat1,lon1) and (lat2,lon2) in meter.
GCDistance= function (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    if (lat1 == lat2 && lon1 == lon2) return 0;
    lat1 *= DE2RA;
    lon1 *= DE2RA;
    lat2 *= DE2RA;
    lon2 *= DE2RA;
    var d = Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon1 - lon2);
    return (radius * Math.acos(d));
};
```

Be aware of the fact that Track Segment are NOT logically connected.

Parsing the GPX using DOM is straight forward.

this code is extract from a lib which in use for years.
here a [sample](http://live2.dotvision.com/live/virtualTour?guid=f0045a3c-6c11-4329-b881-8d8a170538fb&lang=en&intro=true) of where I use it.

Hope this help.
G.

Comment: Output of GCDistance fn is in Kilometers ryt?

Comment: Actually in meter, while the radius is in meter. I updated the answer.